Ordenar la parte numérica de las cadenas de un array en php
Ejemplo:
$array=["ABC-105","BGT 103","ZXS-110","XYZ-101","IYT104","119","SOF-106-B"]

Resultado esperado:
$array=["XYZ-101","BGT 103","IYT104","ABC-105","SOF-106-B","ZXS-110","119"]

Resultado esperado:
 - XYZ-101 
 - BGT 103
 - IYT104
 - ABC-105
 - SOF-106-B
 - ZXS-110
 - 119


Existe usort para ordenar arrays con una función de comparación definida por el usuario. Solo faltaria escribir una que devuelva -1, 0 o 1 dependiendo del orden de las partes numericas.

Se me ocurren un par de soluciones, una ruda con un par de foreach() y otra idéntica a la respuesta de @A.Cedano pero cambiando el explode por preg_replace.  Pero si te lees [ask] y [example] verás que no puedo dártelas, pues nos has mandado una tarea sin mostrar qué has intentado, nos has pegado el enunciado de la tarea tal cual, y este sitio no se rige por los criterios del rincondelvago, lo siento. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para mostrar lo que has hecho y tu pregunta será mejor recibida y podremos ayudarte mejor.

gracias por la ayuda :D ya lo resolví

Pues si lo has resuelto me alegro por ti.  Ahora, como partícipe de esta comunidad, te tocaria agregar tu mismo una respuesta con tu solución, para que así todos aprendamos de todos, y veamos como lo has solucionado. Sino va a parecer que solo quieres que te ayudemos con tus tareas y usar nuestro tiempo en tu único provecho. Léete el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona este sitio, gracias.

Gracias a todos por sus aportes, logré resolverlo de esta manera:
$array = ["ABC-105", "BGT 103", "ZXS-110", "XYZ-101", "IYT104", "119", "SOF-106-B"];

function ordenar_por_numeros($array) {
    usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', $a, $numero_a);
        preg_match('/\d+/', $b, $numero_b);
        $numero_a = intval($numero_a[0]);
        $numero_b = intval($numero_b[0]);
        return $numero_a - $numero_b;
    });
    return $array;
}

$array_ordenado = ordenar_por_numeros($array);

print_r($array_ordenado);

Resultado:
Array
(
    [0] => XYZ-101
    [1] => BGT 103
    [2] => IYT104
    [3] => ABC-105
    [4] => SOF-106-B
    [5] => ZXS-110
    [6] => 119
)


Puedes lograrlo con usort(), strcmp() y explode().
Por ejemplo:
$array=["ABC-105","BGT-103","ZXS-110","XYZ-101","IYT-104"]

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(explode("-", $a)[1], explode("-", $b)[1]);
});

# Sólo para prueba ...
var_dump($array);  

Salida:
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "XYZ-101"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "BGT-103"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "IYT-104"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "ABC-105"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "ZXS-110"
}


muchas gracias me ayudó bastante :D

Se me ocurre algo raro, sin usar ciclos, pero hace lo que pides.
Primero se le pasa una función a todos los elementos del array que solo deja los números (ver array_map). Luego esos números son ordenados por valor pero sin alterar los índices (ver asort). Finalmente se vuelve a generar otro array a partir de los índices del array ordenado.
$func1 = fn($elem)=>preg_replace('/\D/', '', $elem); // retorna solo números
$nums = array_map($func1, $array); // Array de cadenas numéricas
asort($nums, SORT_REGULAR); // $nums -> [3=>"101", 1=>"103", ..., 5=>"119"]

$func2 = fn($idx)=>$array[$idx]; // Retorna un elemento de un array
$res = array_map($func2, array_keys($nums)); // $res -> ["XYZ-101", "BGT 103", ..., "119"]

[ Advertencia ] en este caso SORT_REGULAR hace comparaciones numéricas, o sea, si tienes (por ejemplo) un 82, estará antes que un 136. Si quieres que la comparación sea tipo cadena, cambiar a SORT_STRING

muchas gracias me ayudó bastante :D
